# asp.net changing master site layout runtime

Tags: asp.net

I have the code below on my master page of my asp.net site and at run time it making it into table and mt menu are not being seen any ideas why this could be happening.

I have used firebug to check the code and i am able to see that the code has changed when it is run

```
<form runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="roundPanel">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cisi.png" 
                        ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Professional Refresher Manager
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">

                <asp:Label ID="lblBreadCrumb" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                           </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" CssClass="productHeading"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
                    EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="5" >
                    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="menuindex" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Modules.aspx" Text="Modules"  
                            PopOutImageUrl="~/images/ratingStarFilled.gif" Value="Modules">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/AddModule.aspx" Text="Add New" 
                                ToolTip="Add New Module" Value="Add New"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Page Templates" Value="pages">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Resources" Value="Resources">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="addResource.aspx" Text="Add New" Value="Add New">
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="catManager" Value="catManager" NavigateUrl="~/categoryManager.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/reports/reportsDefault.aspx" Text="Reports" 
                            Value="Reports">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/reports/reportsDefault.aspx" Text="Views" 
                                Value="Views"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/reports/Candidates.aspx" Text="Candidates" 
                                Value="Candidates"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
                </div>
                        </div>&nbsp;<div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:RoundedCornersExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel1"></asp:RoundedCornersExtender>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the CSS and seeing if it is a styling problem?

Comment: I have tried removing the css the scripts and still the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blow you can add the name of of the file from the database and add code below to page load method and will add css file at run time

```
 HtmlLink subcss = new HtmlLink();
        subcss.Href = Name of CSS file to be loaded from database.;
        subcss.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
        subcss.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(subcss);
```